# How do I get the height of an XNA SpriteFont?

Tags: xna, fonts

I have some text in a spritefont and I need to know the height in pixels.

I would have thought that MeasureString() would get me close to it, but it seems to just be about length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MeasureString() returns to you a Vector2 where the X is the width and Y is the height of the text.

Also the SpriteFont class has a LineSpacing member that gives you the height of a line, including text and blank space.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritefont_members.aspx